# Is it possible to have a valueBox be updated by fileInput and also display a modal or popup?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive

I'm wondering how one would have a user input a csv and have a valueBox appear with the number of rows contained in that csv. That valueBox should also have the ability to display a modal of the data the user inputted when clicked.

The issue that's being had is that I'm able to get the valueBox to display the number of rows but not the modal when clicked.

This is what is working to display the number of rows but the modal pop up doesn't work.

I appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

```
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test Bed"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      fileInput("file", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      valueBoxOutput("fulldata")
    )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$file)) return(NULL)
    read.csv(input$file$datapath)
  })
  
  output$fulldata <- renderValueBox({
    div(id = "clickdiv",
        valueBox(nrow(data()), subtitle = "Total Rows"))
  })
  
  onclick("clickdiv", showModal(modalDialog(
    title = "Test",
    renderDataTable(data())
  )))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change couple of things.

1. When using `shinyjs` library include `useShinyjs()` in UI.
2. Add `id` ("clickdiv") for valuebox in UI, because when you pass it from `renderValueBox` it gets overwritten.

```
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test Bed"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    fluidRow(
      fileInput("file", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      div(id = "clickdiv", valueBoxOutput("fulldata"))
    )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$file)) return(NULL)
    read.csv(input$file$datapath)
  })
  
  output$fulldata <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(nrow(data()), subtitle = "Total Rows")
  })
  
  onclick("clickdiv", showModal(modalDialog(
    title = "Test",
    renderDataTable(data())
  )))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]